# Alternative of orgmode

Tags: neovim

I really like how vim is very light-weight compared to other text editor out there. However, this last 3 month, I stumble upon spacemacs. While spacemacs trying it's best by supporting vim's key binding (via evil mode), I don't really like how it consumes my memory.

One of the main reason I use spacemacs is merely because of emacs plugin named orgmode (http://orgmode.org/). I use it for note-taking as well as agenda.

How can I use orgmode by only using vim/neovim + tmux? (Either by using vim plugin or independent program)

So far, I find https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode as the best alternative. But it lacks some features.

**EDIT**

I'll let this question opened since it will let everyone share interesting answers.

However I find the best solution is just use tmux. Make two panels, let one of the panel run vim, while the other one run spacemacs with only minimal amount of layers (I only activate org-mode). The memory consumption is quite low (~ 27 MB). So, my biggest problem is already solved.
[image: tmux with spacemacs and spacevim side by side]

Answer (score 3):

For to-do items specifically, there's [Todo.txt](http://todotxt.com) (though that doesn't require vim, just any text editor).

Comment: Nice. need to check this too....

Answer (score 1):

I just use [`vim-markdown`](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown). I have `vim-orgmode` just for `.org` files.

And there is also [vim-swoop](https://github.com/pelodelfuego/vim-swoop) which maps <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to **l**ook up strings.

Spacemacs, has <kbd>SPC</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> for `helm-swoop`.

Answer (score 0):

I think [vimoutliner](https://github.com/vimoutliner/vimoutliner) would probably be a good option. I've also found [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) helpful in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately, either vimoutliner or vimwiki are both subset feature of org-mode (cmiiw)